# React why the state is not updating when calling a function to initialize it?

Tags: reactjs

Playing with `React` those days. I know that calling `setState` in async. But setting an initial value like that :

`const [data, setData] = useState(mapData(props.data))`

should'nt it be updated directly ?

Bellow a codesandbox to illustrate my current issue and here the code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const data = [{ id: "LION", label: "Lion" }, { id: "MOUSE", label: "Mouse" }];

const mapData = updatedData => {
  const mappedData = {};
  updatedData.forEach(element => (mappedData[element.id] = element));
  return mappedData;
};

const ChildComponent = ({ dataProp }) => {
  const [mappedData, setMappedData] = useState(mapData(dataProp));

  console.log("** Render Child Component **");

  return Object.values(mappedData).map(element => (
    <span key={element.id}>{element.label}</span>
  ));
};

export default function App() {
  const [loadedData, setLoadedData] = useState(data);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

  const filterData = () => {
    return loadedData.filter(element =>
      filter ? element.id === filter : true
    );
  };

  //loaded comes from a useEffect http call but for easier understanding I removed it

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setFilter("LION")}>change filter state</button>
      <ChildComponent dataProp={filterData()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

So in my understanding, when I click on the button I call `setFilter` so `App` should rerender and so `ChildComponent` with the new filtered data.

I could see it is re-rendering and `mapData(updatedData)` returns the correct filtered data **BUT** `ChildComponent` keeps the old state data.

Why is that ? Also for some reason it's rerendering two times ?

I know that I could make use of `useEffect(() => setMappedData(mapData(dataProp)), [dataProp])` but I would like to understand what's happening here.

**EDIT**: I simplified a lot the code, but `mappedData` in ChildComponent must be in the state because it is updated at some point by users actions in my real use case

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-mestorf-kpe8c?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useState` hook gets its argument on the very first initialization. So when the function is called again, the hook yields always the original set.

By the way, you do not need a state there:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ dataProp }) => {
  //const [mappedData, setMappedData] = useState(mapData(dataProp));
  const mappedData = mapData(dataProp);

  console.log("** Render Child Component **");

  return Object.values(mappedData).map(element => (
    <span key={element.id}>{element.label}</span>
  ));
};
```

EDIT: this is a modified version in order to keep the `useState` you said to need. I don't like this code so much, though! :(

```
const ChildComponent = ({ dataProp }) => {
  const [mappedData, setMappedData] = useState(mapData(dataProp));

  let actualMappedData = mappedData;
  useMemo(() => {
      actualMappedData =mapData(dataProp);
    },
    [dataProp]
  )

  console.log("** Render Child Component **");

  return Object.values(actualMappedData).map(element => (
    <span key={element.id}>{element.label}</span>
  ));
};
```

Comment: I simplified a lot my real use case, but setMappedData is actually called when some actions occurs. So I need it to be in the state.

Comment: then you can't have a double source data. You must choose if to update from the properties, or to keep the stored state.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, having the non filtered data in the parent component, and the filtered data in the child is not the best. But I am not sure to understand why useState would give the first initialized value. If I rerender the parent, the init value should change ?

Comment: I updated the answer...it also depends on your actual code. It's pretty hard to give a general approach when it's not clear how the software should behave.

Answer (score 0):

Your child component is storing the mappedData in state but it never get changed.
you could just use a regular variable instead of using state here:

```js
const ChildComponent = ({ dataProp }) => {
  const mappedData = mapData(dataProp);

  return Object.values(mappedData).map(element => (
    <span key={element.id}>{element.label}</span>
  ));
};
```

Comment: Yes in the example I agree with you, but in my real use case mappedData must be in the state

Comment: then you should use useEffect in your child component to call setMappedData every time the dataProp changes